# Larger horizontal committee table in yathesis class

Tags: yathesis

Is it possible to increase the width of the committee table in yathesis? The names of the universities are all broken up and I want some to remain on the line.

I know that yathesis leaves the right most part of the table to designate the committee president but since this is before the defense, a president hasn't been chosen, so I can really increase the width of the table.

For example, in the following table, for Germaine, Verlaine and Baudelaire, the line is broken in their presentation(Université P13, CNRS and ULCO) while the right hand side has the Committee president designation.

[image: Example of table]

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There isn't much compilable code. It's all hidden in the implementation of the class. One writes for example '\examiner
[associateprofessor,affiliation=Université de Paris~13]{Sophie}{Germain}' in a precise file and in the document class one just adds \maketitle and it's all done internally in the class. I want to avoid going in the source files I don't know much about it.

Comment: I think have to modify the class file. You should replace `\begin{minipage}[c][\YAD@otherboxheight][c]{\YAD@titleboxwidth}` by
 `\begin{minipage}[c][\YAD@otherboxheight][c]{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}` (about line 2680 in yathesis.cls)

Comment: you could also probably proceed with the `etoolbox` package

Comment: thank you for reply. I tried your first modification `\textwidth-2\fbo‌​xsep-2\fboxrule` but got an undefined control sequence and an illegal unit of measure error. Also how should I use the etoolbox. I tried to play with that parameter but nothing changed

Comment: you've modified the class file? Because all lengths `\textwidth` `\fbo‌​xsep` `\fboxrule` are well defined I believe.

Comment: It seems that `\fbo‌​xsep` is undefined. I tried playing with that parameter a bit but it didn't change the size of my table sadly.

Comment: strange, it should be defined I believe. I will not be able to fix your issue without an ECM. Please prepare it (with the yathesis class it is not so easy) and provide a link to download the files.

Answer (score 3):

If a president hasn't been chosen, you can just for the moment use the  `\examiner` macro instead of the `\committeepresident` one.

The design of the title page is indeed sadly hard coded (plans to change this but no before few months) so the best way to achieve your need is to redefine some part of it, here the (private) macro `\YAD@committee@tabular` which defines a tabular, the specification of which (that is by default `>{\itshape}llp{5cm}l`) being easily changed.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[mainlanguage=english]{yathesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%
% Modification of the committee tabular 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\YAD@committee@tabular}{%
  \small%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{>{\itshape}llp{8cm}l}
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\bfseries\YAD@translation{committeemembers}}%
    \\[.25cm]
    \DTLforeach*{YAD@staffs}{%
      \YAD@the@staff=YAD@the@staff%
    }{%
      %
      \YAD@display@staff{\YAD@the@staff}%
    }%
  \end{tabular}%
}%
\makeatother
%
\supervisor[professor,affiliation=ULCO]{Michel}{de Montaigne}
\cosupervisor[associateprofessor*,affiliation=ULCO]{Charles}{Baudelaire}
\comonitor[associateprofessor,affiliation=ULCO]{Étienne}{de la Boétie}
\referee[professor,affiliation=IHP]{René}{Descartes}
\referee[seniorresearcher,affiliation=CNRS]{Denis}{Diderot}
% Currently, we're not sure Victor Hugo will be the committe president...
% \committeepresident[professor,affiliation=ENS Lyon]{Victor}{Hugo}
% ... but we know he will be an examiner
\examiner[professor,affiliation=ENS Lyon]{Victor}{Hugo}
\examiner[associateprofessor,affiliation=Université de Paris~13]{Sophie}{Germain}
\examiner[juniorresearcher,affiliation=INRIA]{Joseph}{Fourier}
\examiner[juniorresearcher*,affiliation=CNRS]{Paul}{Verlaine}
\guest{George}{Sand}
%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]